# How to add number in cell name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to add number in cell name?

Ex.
A2 = 11
A3 = 37

I want type =A1+1 in B2 show 11, or type =A1+2 in B2 show 37.

Any vba code or in excel, please share the information.

Everyday i have to increase name in below formula
='Data Sheet'!E9/'Data Sheet'!E8-1 -> ='Data Sheet'!E10/'Data Sheet'!E9-1

Comment: What is reason to do that? Why not you type directly `=A2`?

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is specify a cell reference and then modify it by adding a number, this should help:

```
=OFFSET(A1,1,0)
=OFFSET(A2,1,0)
```

This function accepts a cell reference and offsets it by the specified number of columns and rows, and returns the value from that cell.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, Actually, i change cell name on every day in formula ex. A1 - day one, A2 - day2, ...... A30 day 30.